# How can I slow down this js with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to slowly rotate the letters in a string using 2 second pauses.

I'm trying to use `setTimeout(function, delay)` but it doesn't pause it runs the entire script in under a second.  How can I do this?

My code is at https://jsfiddle.net/6un4xhuj/

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>JS</h1>
<h2 id='for'>For: String Rotations</h2>
<h3 id='result'>Result:</h3>
<h4></h4>
<span id="end_of_results"></span>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
'use strict';
function display(string) {
  $("span#end_of_results").before( $( "<h4>" + string + "</h4>" ) );
}
var string="rotate me";
for (var i = 0; i <= string.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(display(string), 2000);
  string=string[0,string.length - 1] + string.slice(0,-1);
}
```

I get this output but all of it immediately, not step by step.

[image]

Comment: setTimeout is async, which means the for loop is completing inmediately. Also... you are calling display directly instead of passing the function reference. I can write a quick solution if you want

Comment: you have to use callback functions to accomplish what you are trying to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the loop and just recurse the same function passing in the string each time. This code repeats without end so you might want to add a condition as per your requirements.

```
function thing(string) {
  string = string[0, string.length - 1] + string.slice(0,-1);
  $("h2#result").html( $( "<h3>" + string + "</h3>" ) );
  setTimeout(thing, 2000, string);
}

thing(string);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nb05mkdq/6/)

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` takes a function in your argument. In your code `setTimeout(display(string), 2000);`, you pass the **result** of invoking the function `display(string)` into setTimeout. To make this more evident, assign it to a variable like this:

```
var result = display(string); // undefined
setTimeout(result, 2000); // Not right
```

You'll need to use something like [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), or just create a function that returns a function:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  // Modify your string here
  string=string[0,string.length - 1] + string.slice(0,-1);
  display(string)
}, 2000);
```

Comment: In `setTimeout(display(string), 2000);` the function `display()` is run first and it's result is passed to `setTimeout`. That's why the anonymous function  (the last code snippet) is most effective - we are passing a function rather than the result of a function

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout is async, which means the for loop is completing immediately. Also... you are calling display directly instead of passing the function reference. The same algorithm using callbacks would be like this:

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w1x0csp9/

```
'use strict';
var i = 0;
var string="rotate me";
function display() {
  if(i > string.length) {
    return;
  }
  $("span#end_of_results").before( $( "<h4>" + string + "</h4>" ) );
  string = string[0,string.length - 1] + string.slice(0,-1);
  i++;
  setTimeout(display, 2000);
}

display();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are beginning the 2 second wait immediately for all instances of setTimeout. <strike>The simplest way to fix your code is to increase the wait each time you go through your loop:</strike>

change this:

```
setTimeout(display(string), 2000);
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(display(string), (i+1)*2000);
```

Alternatively you could make a single HTML element update on a 2 second interval using `setInterval()` like this:

```
<div class="rotating-text"> rotate me</div>
<script>
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.rotating-text').each(function(){
      var string = $(this).text();
      string = string[0,string.length - 1] + string.slice(0,-1);
      $(this).text(string);
    });
  }, 2000);
</script>
```

This example applies to everything with a class `rotating-text`

http://codepen.io/t3hpwninat0r/pen/eZVYqw

Comment: @Andy I just tried it, the function is evaluated before the timer begins. My apologies, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted andy's answer, also based on it, I create this version to only scroll once:

```
<h1>JS</h1>
<h2 id='for'>For: String Rotation</h2>
<h2 id='result'>Result:</h2>

'use strict';

function rotate(string) {
  string = string[0, string.length - 1] + string.slice(0,-1);
  $("h2#result").html( $( "<h3>" + string + "</h3>" ) ).animate(100);
  rotations+=1
  if (rotations > string.length) {
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(rotate, 50, string);
}

var string="rotate this string ";
var rotations=0
rotate(string);
```

fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/xb865yw6/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.queue()` , `.delay()`

```js
"use strict";

var elem = $("h2#result");

var string = "rotate this string";

elem.append("<br>" + string)
.queue("_fx", $.map(Array(string.length), function(value) {
  return function(next) {
    string = string[0,string.length - 1] + string.slice(0,-1);
    $(this).delay(2000).queue(function() {
      $(this).append("<br>" + string).dequeue();
      next()
    })
  }
})).dequeue("_fx")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<h1>JS</h1>
<h2 id='for'>For: String Rotation</h2>
<h2 id='result'>Result:</h2>
```